# datagridview rowsremoved event gets called every time data loads

Tags: winforms, events, datagridview

The datagridview rowsremoved event gets called every time the data gets loaded. It also makes sense to a certain extent that every time the data loads, the existing rows are removed. so technically the event should get called.

But how do i differenciate that from the actual delete button getting pressed. I don't think the key events should be used, that wouldn't be a clean approach.

Any help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [UserDeletedRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.userdeletedrow.aspx) event instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is how we check to make sure the data has rows first:

```
If dataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
End If
```

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.userdeletingrow.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could have a private boolean variable to know when you are loading and when you are not.

```
private bool IsLoading { get; set; }
```

In the form Load event, you set the variable

```
private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.IsLoading = true;
// do stuff
    this.IsLoading = false;
}

private void DataGridView_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
{
            if (this.IsLoading)
            {
                return;
            }

   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Does not help. As the RowsRemoved (shown in the callstack) isn't called because of setting a DataSource to the DataGridView only. Its also called from `System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(bool value = true)` the first time the object is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the event handler before loading the grid, and then re-add it afterward?

Comment: I have been trying to do that but which event do I re-add it afterward?

Comment: You re-add the RowsRemoved event, in whatever method you load the grid. Like 
RemoveHandler grid.RowsRemoved, AddressOf someFunction;
LoadData(); 
AddHandler grid.RowsRemoved, AddressOf someFunction;

(sorry, I don't know how to code format in a comment box)